# Set fixed interval at Y-axis ChartJS Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

How do i set a fixed interval at the Y-axis with ChartJS Primefaces using LineChartModel, its is using a interval of 5 but i needed to make a 3 interval. I tried using extender with javascript but it didnt work, tried using methods but couldnt find the right methods.

Comment: have you looked at this example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chartjs/line.xhtml at the CartesianLinearAxes which has properties "ticks"  like this: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/charts/axes/cartesian/linear/CartesianLinearTicks.java

Comment: i found the SetStepSize and it worked, thanks for pointing it out, i completely overlooked this method.

Comment: OK I posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stepSize` in the ChartsJS model object provided for Axes in the PrimeFaces model.

See: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/charts/axes/cartesian/linear/CartesianLinearTicks.java

```java
/**
 * Used to provide cartesian linear ticks. CartesianLinearTicks extends {@link CartesianTicks}
 */
public class CartesianLinearTicks extends CartesianTicks {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private boolean beginAtZero;
    private Number min;
    private Number max;
    private Number maxTicksLimit;
    private Number precision;
    private Number stepSize;
    private Number suggestedMax;
    private Number suggestedMin;
```